# Getting TypeError: this is not a typed array using Buffer.from in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha / Chai to unit test a library that has recently started using nodejs' Buffer objects to solve a different problem.

I get this error message in the unit test:

```
TypeError: this is not a typed array. 
at Function.from (native) 
at Object.hashesMatch (index.js:29:18
at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:25:22)
```

Line 29 of index.js is where I'm using nodejs' Buffer...

```
var b = Buffer.from ('some string or other');
```

I can't find a polyfill or workaround so would be grateful for suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You might be using an old version of Node.js.

`Buffer.from` [was introduced](https://nodejs.org/docs/v6.0.0/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe) in version 6.0.0:

> To make the creation of Buffer objects more reliable and less error prone, the various forms of the new Buffer() constructor have been deprecated and replaced by separate Buffer.from(), Buffer.alloc(), and Buffer.allocUnsafe() methods.

There's no reference to this method in [previous versions](https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.9.1/api/buffer.html) of documentiation.

You could either update to 6.0.0 or use a deprecated constructor API, which has the following signature:

```
new Buffer(str[, encoding])
```

Comment: thanks! this worked like a charm. My node was the correct version, it was using the vanilla version of the constructor that did the trick.

Comment: BTW, it was backported to v4.5.0 https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.5.0/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array and v5.10.0 - https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.10.0/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array

Comment: Very helpful @NathanFriedly - Needed those exact version numbers for legacy support on NPM module [apicache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache)

Answer (score 5):

I also got the same error. You can try this

```
var b = new Buffer('some string or other');
```

Second param is encoding (optional). By default encoding will be `utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

There are times when its difficult to update the node version especially if you are using at production so the another solution is

use **"kafka-node": "1.6.2"** or lesser