# how to resolve TypeError : this is not a typed array

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');

Producer = kafka.Producer;

KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage;

client = new kafka.Client();

producer = new Producer(client);

km = new KeyedMessage('key', 'message');

payloads = [
    { topic: 'topic1', messages: 'hi', partition: 0 },
    { topic: 'topic2', messages: ['hello', 'world', km] }
];

producer.on('ready', function () 
{
     producer.send(payloads, function (err, data)
     {
          console.log(data);
     });
});

producer.on('error', function (err) {});
```

//error for that code

```
baaz@bit:~$ node kafka1.js

/home/baaz/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/codec/snappy.js:18

var SNAPPY_MAGIC = Buffer.from(SNAPPY_MAGIC_BYTES).toString('hex');
                        ^
TypeError: this is not a typed array.

at Function.from (native)

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/baaz/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/codec/snappy.js:18:29)

at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)

at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)

at Module.require (module.js:366:17)

at require (module.js:385:17)

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/baaz/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/codec/index.js:4:19)

at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate issue. Please refer to the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899888/getting-typeerror-this-is-not-a-typed-array-using-buffer-from-in-mocha

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer :**
Either increase the node version above 4.5 or
use "kafka-node": "1.6.2" or lesser

**Long Answer**
with node 4.5 and above, node deprecated the old way of creating buffer via a constructor, so all node js version below 4.5 do not have new that support. and kafka-node version > 1.6.2 uses the buffer.from to create the buffer so we have the compatibility issues.

Cheers
Happy coding