# Node-red write data on file

Tags: file, node-red

I have some trouble in use node File in node-red,

I received the following error:

```
TypeError: this is not a typed array.
    at Function.from (native)
    at FileNode.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/nodes/core/storage/50-file.js:67:39)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at FileNode.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at FileNode.Node.receive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/Node.js:215:14)
    at InjectNode.Node.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/Node.js:137:22)
    at InjectNode.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/nodes/core/core/20-inject.js:77:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at InjectNode.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at InjectNode.Node.receive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/Node.js:215:14)
```

I put a picture to show it better.
[image: Error on data append to file]

How I can fix it?

Note:
As asked
Node-RED version: v0.18.4
Node.js  version: v4.2.6

[The node configuration is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOcHT.png)

Comment: Update the question with the details of how you have configured the `file-out` node Also what version of Node-RED are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a quite old version of Node.js. Most likely the root cause of your issue is the same for the one reported here: [Getting TypeError: this is not a typed array using Buffer.from in mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899888/getting-typeerror-this-is-not-a-typed-array-using-buffer-from-in-mocha)

It is worth to upgrade your Node.js to 6.x.x or newer.

Note: I replicated your flow in my system, running:

Node-RED version: v0.19.1  and   Node.js  version: v8.11.1

and it works flawlessly.