# Blinking led light using nodejs

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3

I am performing my first `IOT` project `hello world` blinking I'm trying to started with web of things book and having a problem.

The book is this: https://webofthings.org/2016/10/23/node-gpio-and-the-raspberry-pi/.

But When I trying to run the code I get the error.

```
/home/pi/Desktop/hello_world/node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:9 const HIGH_BUF = Buffer.from('1');

TypeError: this is not a typed array.
at Function.from (native)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/home/pi/Desktop/faizan/node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:9:25)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Desktop/faizan/app.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

The code I'm running is

```js
var onoff = require('onoff');
    
     var Gpio = onoff.Gpio,
     led = new Gpio(4,'out'),
     interval;

     interval = setInterval(function (){
     var value = (led.readSync() + 1) % 2;
     led.write(value, function() {
     console.log("Changed LED state to: " + value);
     });
     }, 2000);

     process.on('SIGINT', function () {
     clearInterval(interval);
     led.writeSync(0);
     led.unexport();
     console.log('Bye, bye!');
     process.exit();
     });
```

Comment: What is your version of Node.js ?

Comment: node version 4.4.6

Comment: Maybe try to update your Node.js [version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36899888/5156280)

Comment: i also updated but not working?